# RShiny: conditional success or error message depending on NULL values

Tags: r, shiny, sweetalert

I am trying to use an `actionBttn` along with the `sendSweetAlert` for a shiny project. Additionally, I would like the user to be notified if there are invalid inputs (a blank text input for example).

To do this, I've tried using `validate` within `observeEvent`, which works to prevent the alert but does not provide an alternative message such as "Please provide a text".

Here is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useSweetAlert(),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("text", "Require This Text"),
  actionBttn(
    inputId = "submit",
    label = "Submit Form",
    color = "success",
    style = "float",
    block = TRUE)
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$submit,
               {
                 validate(
                   need(input$text, message = "Please provide a text")
                 )
                 sendSweetAlert(
                   session = session,
                   title = "Plz halp",
                   text = "Cool stuff doing neat things",
                   type = "success",
                   btn_labels = c("Great")
                 )}
               )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Notice that if there is no text input, the SweetAlert function does not work (a good thing) but there is no alternative message.

Is there a clean way to do this? I considered an if statement to display a SweetAlert error if any values are NULL but couldn't quite fathom how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `isTruthy` to check if the input is filled in:

```
  observeEvent(input$submit,
               if(isTruthy(input$text)) {
                 sendSweetAlert(
                   session = session,
                   title = "Plz halp",
                   text = "Cool stuff doing neat things",
                   type = "success",
                   btn_labels = c("Great")
                 )
               } else {
                 sendSweetAlert(
                   session = session,
                   title = "Plz halp",
                   text = "Please Provide Text",
                   type = "error",
                   btn_labels = c("Sorry!")
                 )
               })
```

Edit: Based on your comment you code do something like this to avoid repeating things. In global or elsewhere,  .ake a function that will validate a list

```
allTruthy <- function(l) {
    all(vapply(l, isTruthy, logical(1)))
}
```

Then in your server, make your form data a reactive list:

```
  t1Form <- reactive(list(
    pop_interest = input$t1_pop_interest,
    int_interest = input$t1_int_interest,
    comparator = input$t1_comparator,
    poutcome = input$t1_poutcome,
    setting = input$t1_setting
  ))
```

Now your form data is in a nice list for use and validation. Then your observer can be:

```
  observeEvent(input$submit,
           if(allTruthy(t1Form())) {
             sendSweetAlert(
               session = session,
               title = "Plz halp",
               text = "Cool stuff doing neat things",
               type = "success",
               btn_labels = c("Great")
             )
           } else {
             sendSweetAlert(
               session = session,
               title = "Plz halp",
               text = "Please Provide Text",
               type = "error",
               btn_labels = c("Sorry!")
             )
           })
```

Comment: That's perfect - thanks a lot! I haven't had a lot of experience with isTruthy so I wasn't quite sure the syntax. This makes sense. I had multiple inputs so I just strung them together with & statements as such:


`if(isTruthy(input$t1_pop_interest) & 
                  isTruthy(input$t1_int_interest) & 
                  isTruthy(input$t1_comparator) &
                  isTruthy(input$t1_poutcome) &
                  isTruthy(input$t1_setting))`

Comment: No problem! Updated my answer based on your use case.

Comment: Brilliant - I hadn't needed to reduce it to a function as I only need to validate once but certainly that is much more generalized! Thank you, again.